# Renaming folders in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs

What's the proper way (sequence of steps) to rename a folder in TFS?  I tried doing it locally then commit but it's not working.  I think you prob have to do it from TFS (server-side) instead right?  But then if you do that and get latest then I guess it'll just update your folder locally and hopefully you don't have any other conflicts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open Source Control Explorer, mark your module, press F2 & enter the new name.
Module will appear in your Pending Changes window with Change type "rename". 

Suppose you had a module named `test.txt` which participated in 3 changesets. It then gets renamed into `itsatest.txt` When I get History for file `itsatest.txt` I get this:[image]

In my hard drive the `test.txt` doesn't exist after the rename.
The same principle works with folders as well.

**EDIT** after comment

> Problem is I did all this renaming locally on my file system...I don't
>   want to lose all these changes because I also changed namespaces in
>   code, etc

I see. 
One way to proceed is to copy the entire directory somewhere out of your workspace. 
Then delete it from your workspace and retake it from source control with 'Get specific version' and 'Overwrite all files even if the local version matches the specified version'. 
Proceed with the rename & checkin.

 Perform a directory compare between your locally stored dir & the one you 've just renamed. All your changed files should appear. 
Check them out & copy-paste them manually into your workspace.
This should take care of the situation.

---

I'm pretty sure I remember another TFS SO post, where the recommendation was 'never mix pending changes with pending renames' - can't seem to find it ATM...

Comment: `rename the folder to just be all caps`: shouldn't matter.

Comment: When I try to rename my "BusinessLayer" folder to "BUSINESSLOGIC" I get the error "Item name already exists on disk".  Yes I did rename it locally but so what!  TFS should be smart enough to evaluate that in the diff.  Obviously it's not capable and barfs all over on me.

Comment: Please go ahead and erase the directory you have mapped. If you already have a "BUSINESSLOGIC" from any source, you 'll get trouble - that's true. Then get latest from TFS again with 'Get specific version' and 'Overwrite all files even if the local blah'. Then retry. It should work (at least it does in my kitchen...)

Comment: Problem is I did all this renaming locally on my file system...I don't want to lose all these changes because I also changed namespaces in code, etc.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5196/discussion-between-pantelif-and-coffeeaddict)

Comment: I think it would be benificial to discuss here because if you shouldn't be / can't rename locally without TFS throwing up on a rename and you MUST do renames to folders on the server, then that's pretty important for all to know who haven't used TFS in a while like me (been using excellent Subversion for the past 5 years...after TFS)

Comment: ok, thanks I think I figured out that you can't do this as you stated...don't make changes locally when you have pending changes....I'll update this post with the right answer once I test and get this working again.